# Get NTFS permissions data from Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, file-permissions, ntfs, windows-server

In one domain, we have NTFS file share (Windows Server 2014+ machine) and Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

I have added Ubuntu machine to this domain using Samba. Now I can see Active Directory groups and users and login to Ubuntu machine with domain users.

The task is to get information about NTFS file share permissions to Ubuntu machine programmatically. 
Python solutions are preferred, but any advice will be appreciated.